# Is there a material that changes local conductivity

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I hope this is the right forum to ask this question. Is there a material (preferably thin, like a membrane) that changes its local conductivity (by that I mean the permeability for an electric field; I hope it's the right term) upon excitation with light or heat? I have no idea where to start my search for something like that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any semiconductor will do this.

Comment: Who would have thought that the answer is that easy. Just to make sure that I understand you correctly, I can have a sheet of semi-conducting material, locally shine a laser onto it and it will change its conductivity properties?

Comment: Yes - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoconductivity

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since I cannot accept your answer, I can at least upvote your comment.

Comment: You should probably accept Manish's answer since he at least put in the effort to write one :-) Accepting an answer flags the question as "answered" otherwise it sits in the "Unanswered questions" queue forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Semiconductors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductors) are the best examples of this, they have very significant temperature coefficients.

In general, any conductor has [a temperature dependence regarding conductivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Temperature_dependence). Generally, heat decreases conductivity for metals. Semiconductors can go both ways; [thermistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor) with both PTC (positive temperature coefficients) and NTC are readily available.

---

Regarding light: Metals generally aren't affected by light, but semiconductors are. When light strikes a semiconductor, electron-hole pairs are excited to the conduction band, increasing the conductivity. [LDRs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) and [photodiodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode) are examples of this. (Technically, *all* LEDs are photodiodes of a sort, just like all speakers can work as weak microphones)

Comment: I have a small follow-up question. I am actually searching for some kind of foil or film for which I can change the permeability for an electric field locally with e.g. a laser. If I understood it correctly, such a thing is part of a laser printer. Do you know whether such foils exist and where one could buy it (I don't have the right terms to google it; I always end up at patents). Thanks.

Comment: @fabee: Not sure. Liquid crystals seem like a good idea, but they're not linear dielectrics. However, photodiodes are affected by lasers.